# how to pass the query data from SOQL to child object

Tags: soql

my code is

```
Account[] objAcc = [select Id,name,(Select id,FirstName,LastName, from contacts), from Account where Name='Test Account'];

Contact[] con=objAcc.contacts;
```

this code throw an error as variable contacts does not exist. but when i use for loop as

```
for(Account accData:objAcc ) {
    Contact[] contct=accData.contacts;
}
```

it works well.
do can't pass data without using for loop.

I am a learner at salesforce so if there is any mistakes plzz resolve them..

Comment: **objAcc** is not an instance of account here but a list of Account and that's why is throwing an error. If you are looking for only one particular Account instance's Contact list then add list not empty check. If isn't empty list then you can use syntax **Contact[] con=objAcc[0].contacts**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<Account> objAcc = [select Id,name,(Select id,FirstName,LastName, from contacts), from Account where Name='Test Account'];
```

See your contact is  inside the account.So you have to access objAcc.contacts
Id you want to iterate objAcc.contacts that should be contact type

```
for(Account ac:objAcc ){
 for(Contact c:ac:objAcc.Contacts){

 //YOU CAN Access contact records here }}
```